# Compiling/Knitting Rmarkdown on Windows vs OS X results in very different PDF size?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown

I am working on a paper with my advisor, and we are preparing the article using Rmarkdown (knitr), compiling to PDF (with some custom LaTeX macros). I am using OS X, while my advisor works on Windows.

One oddity we have noticed is that if I knit the PDF on OS X it results in a vastly larger PDF than if he knits it on Windows - the same Rmd file, with exactly the same content and YAML and so forth.  For example, here is the recent Dropbox history of the PDF (my edits at the top):

[image: File sizes by user]

What I would like to know is if anyone else has noticed this issue, and if there is some way to make the knitted PDF consistent across the operating systems?  I do not even know where to begin to investigate what is causing the difference.

Comment: I would guess the difference lies either in the versions of pandoc or the Latex compiler used. You could also compare the ouput `R Markdown` in RStudio when compiling the Rmd.